# Flash Air : a "new Video()" turns screen black

Tags: android, flash, video, air

I am developing a Flash AIR 3.5 Android app with Flash Builder 4.6.

If I put this code at the beginning of my app :

```
import flash.media.Video;
...
        new Video();
```

then the screen just goes black (testing on an XPeria Arc S). The app **IS running** (I can hear it), I just get no visual feedback.

If fact, the screen goes black at any point whatsoever that I may put a "new Video()" : even when the app has started correctly and is running!!!

Of crouse, a "new Video()" doesn't serve anything by itself, I just want to pinpoint the source of the problem.

Comment: Show more of your code please. For example, I am assuming you add the video to the stage... You can't see the object until it is added to the stage. So its likely that simply new'ing up a Video object is not the cause. If you add a Video object but never play anything you will get a black box. But it sounds like you are playing something b/c you hear audio -- if you are getting audio only it could be a problem with the format/encoding of your video file. Alas, this is only speculation, since you didn't show any real code or explain what your app is trying to do.

Comment: Like I said, the "new Video" causes the problem by itself alone, without adding it on stage at all. Seems like a serious Air 3.5 bug or incompatibility with my Xperia. When desktop-debugging everything works fine, it's on the device that it goes black.

Comment: I'm seeing a very similar problem on the asus memopad 10.1 - the video appears, but the rest of the application is blacked out, until you switch away from the app and back again. what is your app's render mode set to?

Comment: also, does your app config xml include the <containsVideo>true</containsVideo> node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your app's render mode to 'GPU,' and in your app config xml, add `<containsVideo>false</containsVideo>` as a child of the `<android />` node.